# How do I convert bitset to array of bytes/uint8?

Tags: c++, arrays, bitset

I need to extact bytes from the bitset which may (not) contain a multiple of CHAR_BIT bits. I now how many of the bits in the bitset I need to put into an array. For example,

the bits set is declared as   `std::bitset < 40>  id;`

There is a separate variable `nBits` how many of the bits in `id` are usable. Now I want to extract those bits in multiples of CHAR_BIT. I also need to take care of cases where `nBits % CHAR_BIT != 0`. I am okay to put this into an array of uint8

Comment: Harsh... if you had less than sizeof(unsigned long) bits, this would be straightforward using `bitset::to_ulong`. As it is, I don't think there is a simple solution. `std::bitset` doesn't have something like `data()` as `std::vector` does (though the gcc version has an undocumented and experimental `_M_getdata` function which is just that...)`. Since there is no other thing, you can only access the individual bits separately. Or, serialize to a string or go via a stream, but neither of these is particularly efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no good way within the language, assuming you need for than the number of bits in an `unsigned long` (in which case you could use `to_ulong`). You'll have to iterate over all the bits and generate the array of bytes yourself.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), which can be converted to a range of "blocks" using [boost::to_block_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#to_block_range).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef uint8_t Block; // Make the block size one byte
    typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<Block> Bitset;

    Bitset bitset(40); // 40 bits

    // Assign random bits
    for (int i=0; i<40; ++i)
    {
        bitset[i] = std::rand() % 2;
    }

    // Copy bytes to buffer
    std::vector<Block> bytes;
    boost::to_block_range(bitset, std::back_inserter(bytes));
}
```

Comment: One gotcha to watch out for is that the inner type of the vector needs to match the block type that was used to construct the bitset (in this case, `unsigned char`).  If the bitset has 4-byte blocks but the vector has 1-byte blocks, `to_block` will silently chop off the latter 3 bytes of each block.

So, it's somewhat safer to change the vector declaration in Emile's answer to `std::vector<Bitset::Block> bytes`.

Comment: Correction to my comment: the inner type is `Bitset::block_type`, not `Bitset::Block`.

Comment: @prideout: Added `Block` typedef to avoid the situation you describe.

Answer (score 3):

With standard C++11, you can get the bytes out of your 40-bit `bitset` with shifting and masking. I didn't deal with handling different values rather than 8 and 40 and handling when the second number is not a multiple of the first.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    constexpr int numBits = 40;

    std::bitset<numBits> foo(0x1234567890);
    std::bitset<numBits> mask(0xff);

    for (int i = 0; i < numBits / 8; ++i) {
        auto byte =
            static_cast<uint8_t>(((foo >> (8 * i)) & mask).to_ulong());
        std::cout << std::hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << static_cast<int>(byte) << std::endl;
    }
}
```