# How to split bitset of any size into list of 64 bits bitsets?

Tags: c++, bitset

I have a bitset of any size and I would like to know the fastest way to get a list of 64 bits bitsets from my original bitset ?

For example, from `bitset<10000> b('010001110 ...')`, I would like to get a list of 64 bits bitsets containing the 1st 64th bits, then the next 64th bits from my original bitset, and so on.

Comment: What should happen with the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't any functionality to efficiently do this operation straight from the STL. You'd have to go bit by bit or you can shift and mask, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58979953/1673776) answer.

However, giving credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9081167/1673776)

> You can use [boost::dynamic_bitset](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), which can be converted to a range of "blocks" using boost::to_block_range.